# getting Parsererror in remix ide

Tags: python, ethereum, solidity, remix

I am learning **blockchain development** from youtube and I was copy-pasting things but the error wont made me compile code

Code:

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract simple storage {

    uint256 favoriteNumber;
    bool favoriteBool;

    struct people
    {

        uint256 favoriteNumber;
        string name;
    }
    People[]public people{
        function store(uint256 _favoriteNumber) public {

            favoriteNumber =_favoriteNumber;
        }
    }


    
}
```

The error:

```
ParserError: Expected ';' but got '{'
--> contracts/simplestorage.sol:14:26:
|
14 | People[]public people{
| ^
```

Comment: Why is this tagged `python`? That's not Python code.

Answer (score 0):

There's a bunch of stuff wrong in your code:

1. You have an extra `}` at the end
2. Your contract name should be 1 word, with the camel case convention
3. people in`struct people` should be capitalized
4. You missing a space in between `People[] public people` and the statement ends with a `;` not `{` when your declaring a global variable

```js
pragma solidity ^0.8.7;

contract SimpleStorage {

    uint256 favoriteNumber;
    bool favoriteBool;

    struct People
    {
        uint256 favoriteNumber;
        string name;
    }

    People[] public people;

        function store(uint256 _favoriteNumber) public {
            favoriteNumber =_favoriteNumber;
        }
    }
```